# Identifying and removing unknown Sound device

Tags: macos, audio, driver

Since I use my Mac for presentations at workshops and conferences, I've apparently picked up a whole bunch of "exotic" drivers that come as part of presentation AV equipment. The latest addition seems to be the "`Data Source Item 0`" in the Sounds-drop down. I think I found the culprit in the `Audio MIDI Setup` (at least there's an audio driver from *one* of those AV-rooms), but the <kbd>-</kbd> button is not available for *any* device.

How do I go about identifying where this is coming from and removing it?

[image: Screenshot of Sounds-drop down]

As @Allan suggested, system profile below -- how would I go about axing the `ESHOW`-device:

```
$ system_profiler SPAudioDataType
Audio:

    Devices:

        Built-in Microphone:

          Input Channels: 2
          Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
          Current SampleRate: 44100
          Transport: Built-in
          Input Source: Internal Microphone

        Built-in Output:

          Default System Output Device: Yes
          Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
          Output Channels: 2
          Current SampleRate: 44100
          Transport: Built-in
          Output Source: Internal Speakers

        ESHOW录音:

          Default Input Device: Yes
          Default Output Device: Yes
          Input Channels: 2
          Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
          Output Channels: 2
          Current SampleRate: 44100
          Transport: Virtual
          Input Source: Data Source Item 0
          Output Source: Data Source Item 0
```

Comment: Have you tried removing USB devices from your computer and seeing if it disappears?

Comment: You can get some good information by issuing the command `system_profiler SPAudioDataType`  Post the output to your question.

Comment: @drivec There's no USB device connected (one of the projectors came with a wifi-ish USB dongle that also contained drivers for MacOS).

Comment: From the looks of things, you apparantly have a virtual sound device that was created called "ESHOW".  It says it's an Apple product, but I don't know of any Apple product by that name.  Did you install any software for these projectors?

Comment: Yup, that came from one of the presentation equipments...can't find any files, kernel modules or service with a related name.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I also suffered from this problem after installing a software to use a wireless projector. Though the name is not ESHOW but DongleAudio in my case, I guess this works for you.

1. In Terminal.app, `cd /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/HAL`
2. Remove the driver by `rm -rf ESHOW.driver` or `rm -rf DongleAudio.driver`
3. Reboot your Mac

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! Not entirely clear why I never found that one, probably because I only used `find` with case-sensitive names or somesuch.

Comment: My rogue audio device is named DeviceName with the input and output both named Default (with the Manufacturer being "ManufacturerName"). The list that's in HAL/ is: 
AirPlay.driver
AppleAVBAudio.driver
AppleTimeSyncAudioClock.driver
BluetoothAudioPlugIn.driver
BridgeAudioSP.driver
iSightAudio.driver
unfortunately I can't really finger any of these as my rogue device...

Comment: @StevenLu Hmm, how about searching it entirely with `grep` and `find` commands?

Comment: I did use Grep and many matches are found in binary files. I will search with a binary hex editor next.

Comment: These are executable binaries that i'm getting hits with and grepping the strings in them is not revealing much. I'm not trained in reverse engineering executables. I am going to ignore this, and if I keep looking into it, I will compare it against what exists in that location on my other macbooks.

Comment: After upgrading to 10.14.6 and the requisite reboot, the mystery sound device has disappeared.

Comment: Apower sound device was not getting removed by any other method. This worked. Kudos.